# Will window.parent access from an third party iframe embedded in public website cause security issue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I am building a react based chat application which will be sandoxed inside an iframe which has the sandbox attribute set to
allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups.

So, users of this application will embed this chat application in their public website (hence the iframe). 
The chat application allows an user to download the chat conversation as an html transcript. 
I am doing this along the following lines:

`let hiddenIFrame = window.parent.document.createElement('iframe');
  hiddenIFrame.setAttribute('style', ' display:none; height:0; width:0 ');
  hiddenIFrame.setAttribute('src', resourceUrl);
  window.parent.document.body.appendChild(hiddenIFrame);`

[N.B.] The chat application communicates with a remote chat server to manage chat rooms/message passing/transcript download.

The code works in the browsers (IE/Edge/Firefox/Chrome). The questions is, since the chat server and the public website have
different origins, will my approach above introduce any security vulnerability for the customer ? If yes, what could be an
alternative solution to allow transcript download which works cross-browser ?

The problem is we need to support firefox 45 esr and above and IE v11 which might not support all HTML5 specs, so approaches of generating  tags and clicking on it does not work always.

Comment: So just a simple `location.href=resourceUrl` inside your own iframe where your chat plugin is running in already won’t do? (Not sure how sandbox flags affect downloads triggered from with the iframe, but this would not be top-level navigation, so I would assume this should work?)

Comment: I tried using location.href=resourceUrl. Unfortunately, the click event does not fire for IE/FF 45 esr. I have a requirement to support FF45+/IE11/Edge/Chrome53+.

Comment: What click event are you talking about?